# Deduce field width from data type in std::format

Tags: c++, format, std, c++20

I'm experimenting with the new C++ 2020 `std::format` function. I would like to represent the output with a width deduced from its type. Currently I have this line:

```
std::wstring wstr = std::format( L"{0:#0{1}x}", ::GetLastError(), sizeof( ::GetLastError() ) * 2 );
```

This results in the value `L"0x000002"`.

- Is `#` supposed to count the `0x` as part of the width? (If I remove it, I get 8 nibbles as expected)
- Is there a better way of formulating this format string, without sizeof thing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is `#` supposed to count the `0x` as part of the width? (If I remove it, I get 8 nibbles as expected)

Yes. There is an example in [[format.string.std]/13](https://eel.is/c++draft/format.string.std#13) which illustrates this. The whole string is 6 characters, including the `0x`:

> ```cpp
> string s2 = format("{:#06x}", 0xa);     // value of s2 is "0x000a"
> ```

This is similar to what `printf` does.

> Is there a better way of formulating this format string, without sizeof thing?

If this is something you want to do often, then you can create your own type and define its formatting internally so that you just write:

```cpp
std::wstring wstr = std::format( L"{}", PrettyHex{::GetLastError()});
```

But that's just moving where the `sizeof` happens - you still need to manually provide it somewhere, there's no shortcut here.

Comment: Thanks, I assume `PrettyHex` is not part the standard but the thing I should define. Can you give some direction where to start? Is this a subclass of something or a template, or what?

Comment: @z32a7ul Yes, that's why the sentence introducing it says "you can create your own type and define its formatting." It's not a subclass of anything. It's just a type, that exists solely to do format `::GetLastError()` in the way you want to format it.

Comment: OK, I looked into creating such a type, and it's not worth the effort.

Answer (score 0):

Anyway, I wrote this specialization. So if someone is interested, here it is:

```
#include <format>
#include <iostream>

typedef unsigned long DWORD;

struct PrettyHex {
    DWORD dwValue;
};

template<>
struct std::formatter< PrettyHex, wchar_t > : std::formatter< std::wstring, wchar_t > {
    auto format( PrettyHex prettyHex, std::wformat_context& context ) {
        std::wstring wstrPrettyHex = std::format( L"0x{:0{}x}", prettyHex.dwValue, sizeof prettyHex.dwValue * 2 );
        return std::formatter< std::wstring, wchar_t >::format( wstrPrettyHex, context );
    }
};

int wmain() {
    DWORD dwTest = 102;
    std::wstring wstrTest = std::format( L"dwTest formatted as DWORD: {}\ndwTest formatted as PrettyHex: {}\n", dwTest, PrettyHex{ dwTest } );
    std::wcout << wstrTest;

    return 0;
}
```